# Storing clicked item position in a variable to be accessed elsewhere

Tags: java, android

I want to store the value that I get from getPosition() which is the position of the clicked item in the arraylist into a variable that I can use later inside another classfor  viewpager to set current item postion.
My question is how to do it?

```
public class PlanetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        protected TextView text;
        public PlanetViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_id);
        }
        public void bind(final String item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getPosition();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can make a static array list variable perhaps.

Comment: Thanks , but I don't prefer a static approach , can you show me how to achieve this?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by not liking static approach? Static variables aren't evil if you know what you are doing. Also, since you don't like it, there no point exploring that option.

Comment: Shared preferences it's an option.

Comment: thank you guys but my java knowledge is limited can you show me how please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sharedpreferences` is good option for your usecase
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

**Write to shared preferences**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), newHighScore);
editor.apply();
```

**Read from shared preferences**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.saved_high_score_default_key);
int highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), defaultValue);
```

You can follow https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shared-preferences-in-android-with-examples/ to implement in your case

Comment: Thank you , it makes sense now